# How to correctly get Form API single checkbox value variable from database?

Tags: 7, forms

I created an `additional_settings` fieldset for node type forms that holds a single checkbox:

```
$form['MY_SETTING']['enabled'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Enable'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('MY_SETTING_' . $form['#node_type']->type, FALSE),
);
```

When I check the checkbox and save the node type form the value gets stored like that: `MY_SETTING_MY_NODETYPE[0] = 'enabled'`. The `#default_value` only understands `TRUE` and `FALSE` and doesn't work with `enabled`. I've sneaked in other modules (p.e. comments module) and have seen that they solved that with constants. But how to apply a constant in that form logic and let it be saved to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use constants in place of string literals, sure, but that's not related to the issue you're having. That's simply a matter of converting the statement you already have to a boolean.

Which is as easy as:

```
$bool_enabled = variable_get('MY_SETTING_' . $form['#node_type']->type, 'disabled') == 'enabled';
$form['MY_SETTING']['#default_value'] = $bool_enabled;
```

Incidentally, the string "enabled" evaluates to `TRUE` in PHP, so it's not possible for it "not to work with `enabled`", it's just that 'disabled' also evaluates to `TRUE`, so you won't ever see a falsey value.

Personally I think the simplest solution is store the variable as an integer, 1 or 0. Then you can just assign it straight to the form element and let PHP's implicit integer -> boolean conversion take over. That's how all core (and contrib, that I've seen) modules handle it.